# Помогите, не срабатывает рекурсия

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет. Пишу мини игру "карточный жребий". Суть ее в том что случайно генерируется число от 1 до 13 и потом div присваивается соответственный класс. Для усложнения задачи написал несколько различных механизмов но до ума не все еще довел, не судите строго. А суть вопроса заключается в некотором решении, для избежания повтора карт. Я использовал рекурсию и поставил ее на условия поиска в массиве, но по какой-то причине она то работает то не работает. Помогите поправить код.

```js
var curArr = [];
var currentCard;
var j = 0;
var rezFind;
var cardLength;
var playerIndex;
var on = 0;

$('.card').click(function() {
  if (j == 0) {
    random();
  }
  rubaha = $(this).attr('class');
  if (rubaha == 'card shirt') {
    $(this).removeClass('shirt').addClass("c" + currentCard);
    curArr[j] = currentCard;
    j++;
    randCheck();
  }
});

function random() {
  currentCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13 + 1);
}

function randCheck() {
  random();
  find();
  if (rezFind == 1) {
    randCheck();
  }
}

function find() {

  for (var i = 0; i < curArr.length; i++) {
    if (currentCard == curArr[i]) {
      rezFind = 1;
    } else {
      rezFind = 0;
    }
  }
}

$('.player').click(function() {
  playerIndex = $(this).index() + 2;
  cardLength = $('.card').length;
  addCard();

});

function addCard() {
  $('.card').removeClass().addClass('card shirt');
  for (var i = 2; i < playerIndex; i++) {

  }
  for (var i = 2; i < cardLength; i++) {

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="playerLength">
    <p class="player player2">X2</p>
    <p class="player player3">X3</p>
    <p class="player player4">X4</p>
    <p class="player player5">X5</p>
  </div>

  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card shirt"></div>
    <div class="card shirt"></div>
    <div class="card shirt"></div>
    <div class="card shirt"></div>
    <div class="card shirt"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Старайтесь не использовать рекурсии в JS насколько это возможно. Рекурсивный вызов всегда влечет за собой лишний расход памяти и дополнительное процессорное время. Лучше такой вызов заменить на цикл. К тому же рекомендуется не хранить в глобальной области видимости переменные вашего функционального модуля, лучше прячьте всё в функцию или объект, за фасадом которого уже скрывается вся реализация вашего решения. Вы только выдавайте интерфейс. Я ниже набросал что-то подобное синглтона на вашу задачу.

```
var cardRandomizer = (function() {
var cardsArr = [],
    cardVariation = 13;
function getNextUniqueCard() {
    //Здесь получим следующую уникальную карту

    //Необходимо проверить что-бы количество выпавших карт было не больше
    //числа вариаций этой колоды, грубо говоря если всего 2 карты, 
    //то нет смысла обрабатывать более двух вариаций
    if (cardsArr.length >= cardVariation) return;

    var pass = true;
    while(pass) {
        currentCard = randomCard(cardVariation);
        for (var i = 0; i < cardsArr.length; i++) {
            if(cardsArr[i] == currentCard) {
                break;
            }
        };

        pass = (i != cardsArr.length);
    };

    cardsArr.push(currentCard);
};

function getNextCard() {
    //Здесь получим просто следующую карту
    currentCard = randomCard(cardVariation);
    cardsArr.push(currentCard);
};

function randomCard(cardVariation) {
    //Здесь задаем алгоритм генерации случайного числа
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * cardVariation + 1);
};

function getCards() {
    //Здесь получаем массив карт
    return cardsArr;
};

function setCardVariation(col) {
    //Здесь должна быть проверка на передаваемый параметр
    cardVariation = col;
};

function clearArrCards() {
    //очистка массива карт
    cardsArr = [];
};

var API = {
    setCardVariation: setCardVariation,
    clearArrCards: clearArrCards,
    getNextUniqueCard: getNextUniqueCard,
    getNextCard: getNextCard,
    getCards: getCards
};

return API;
})();
cardRandomizer.getNextUniqueCard();
cardRandomizer.getNextUniqueCard();
cardRandomizer.getNextUniqueCard();
cardRandomizer.getNextUniqueCard();
cardRandomizer.getNextUniqueCard();
cardRandomizer.getNextUniqueCard();
console.log(cardRandomizer.getCards());
```

Answer (score -1):

Все оказалось очень просто. Не стоило засовывать изменение переменной в цикл, там то функция find и теряла значение. 
Вот как решил проблему.

```
var randCheck = function () {
random();
find();
if (rezFind == 1) {
    rezFind = 0;
    return randCheck();
}
}

var find = function () {

for (var i = 0; i < curArr.length; i++) {
    if (currentCard == curArr[i]) {
        rezFind = 1;
    }
}
}
```